# Tilemap error pygame

Tags: python, pygame, tile

***I know questions on subjects like this have been posted before but I have an error I have not seen in any other questions.***

I am trying to make a tiled background from a 2d array, but when I run it I get this error:

current_tile = textures[tilemap[x,y]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

tilesize = 32
tileswidth = 11
tilesheight = 12

screenwidth = tilesize*tileswidth
screenheight = tilesize*tilesheight
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenheight))

tilemap = [
    [9,3,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,9],
    [8,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,5],
    [8,1,6,9,9,9,9,9,8,1,5],
    [8,1,5,9,9,9,9,9,7,1,5],
    [8,1,6,9,9,9,9,9,7,1,5],
    [8,1,5,9,9,9,9,9,8,1,5],
    [8,1,12,4,2,3,2,4,13,1,5],
    [7,11,10,10,10,11,10,10,10,11,6],
    [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9],
    [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9],
    [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9]
    ]

textures = {
    1 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/1.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    2 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/2.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    3 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/3.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    4 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/4.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    5 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/5.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    6 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/6.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    7 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/7.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    8 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/8.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    9 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/9.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    10 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/10.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    11 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/11.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    12 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/12.jpg").convert_alpha(),
    13 : pygame.image.load("data/tiles/13.jpg").convert_alpha()
    }

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for x in range(tilesheight):
        for y in range(tileswidth):
            current_tile = textures[tilemap[x,y]]
            screen.blit(current_tile, (x*tilesize, y*tilesize))


    screen.fill(0,0,0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should also take note that `screenheight` should be equal to 11 or the code will hit an index error because there are only 11 items in `tilemap`, and `screen.fill(0,0,0)` should be changed to `screen.fill((0,0,0))` to avoid a value error as well.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

To fix this error, you have to use integers (numbers) and not tuple (1,2) as list indices. From what I see, you are trying to do 2-dimensional list[1,2] which is wrong because 2 dimensional arrays/lists are **lists of lists**.
That is why you have to use **tilemap[x][y]**.
Tilemap[x] returns sublist from the tilemap and tilemap[x][y] is *from* *sublist at x, return element y*.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a list with a tuple which is what `tilemap[x,y]` is doing, you want:

```
tilemap[x][y]
```

Which is taking the  element at index x from   sublist at index y:

```
In [7]: tilemap = [
   ...:     [9,3,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,9],
   ...:     [8,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,5],
   ...:     [8,1,6,9,9,9,9,9,8,1,5],
   ...:     [8,1,5,9,9,9,9,9,7,1,5],
   ...:     [8,1,6,9,9,9,9,9,7,1,5],
   ...:     [8,1,5,9,9,9,9,9,8,1,5],
   ...:     [8,1,12,4,2,3,2,4,13,1,5],
   ...:     [7,11,10,10,10,11,10,10,10,11,6],
   ...:     [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9],
   ...:     [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9],
   ...:     [9,9,9,9,7,1,6,9,9,9,9]
   ...:     ]

In [8]: tilemap[0][0]
Out[8]: 9

In [9]: tilemap[1][0]
Out[9]: 8
```

You can also just iterate over the tilemap list:

```
for ind, sub in enumerate(tilemap):
    for i, y in enumerate(sub):
        current_tile = textures[y]
        screen.blit(current_tile, (ind * tilesize, i * tilesize))
```

Comment: Would love to know what is wrong with the correct answer

Comment: I didn't give you the down vote, but you never referenced the `l` variable when you suggested iterating through `tileset`. `l` needs to be declared before the loops, incremented by one at the end of every iteration of `for y in sub:`, and set to 0 again after every iteration of `for ind, sub in enumerate(tilemap):`.

Comment: @Flutterguy135, , that is not the reason my answer was downvoted, it was a troll. The answer below basically regurgitates what I already explained in far more detail and has an upvote so that really explains it all

Comment: I'm not going to argue why you got a down vote, but your code runs now with that edit, so you got an up vote from me.